# How to add user to my own database after supabase creates new users

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I am new to supabase. When a new user signs in or signs up in supabase, I want to add the user to my own database.

I've tried creating a `public.users` supabase database using triggers when a new user joined. And created a database function on the updation of `public.users` database to hit an endpoint, creating a user in my database. This looks complicated. Are there any other ways to simplify this process?

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the query! Quick question - it sounds like you an external database outside of Supabase to store data. Can I confirm that this is the case? 

I'm not too sure about your exact situation but one option is to use Supabase it self to host your data (it's Postgres under the hood) and then have a Foreign key reference on `public.users` which points to `auth.users`.

Feel free to reach out at support [at] supabase.io too if you'd prefer more privacy on application specific details.

Comment: Basically, whenever a row is added into auth.users table(i.e when a user is created), I need to add the user to an external database.

Comment: I see - I'd personally use a database trigger/function which hits a database endpoint/edge function. Not too sure of simpler methods unfortunately. Let's see if anyone else has better suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, I realised that I missed this option - one can probably also use https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html to achieve the same result